# Input C-style string and get the length

Tags: c++, char

The string input format is like this

str1 str2

I DONT know the no. of characters to be inputted beforehand so need to store 2 strings and get their length.
Using the C-style strings ,tried to made use of the scanf library function but was actually unsuccessful in getting the length.This is what I have:

```
// M W are arrays of char with size 25000
   while (T--)
   {
       memset(M,'0',25000);memset(W,'0',25000);
       scanf("%s",M);
       scanf("%s",W);
       i = 0;m = 0;w = 0;
       while (M[i] != '0')
              {
                  ++m; ++i;  // incrementing till array reaches '0'
              }
        i = 0;
       while (W[i] != '0')
              {
                  ++w; ++i;
              }
       cout << m << w;


   }
```

Not efficient mainly because of the `memset` calls.

Note:
I'd be better off using `std::string` but then because of 25000 length input and memory constraints of cin I switched to this.If there is an efficient way to get a string then it'd be good

Comment: Since this is C++ you should use `std:string` and C++ I/O - you can always get a C string from a `std::string` if you really need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the answers already given, I think your code is slightly wrong:

```
   memset(M,'0',25000);memset(W,'0',25000);
```

Do you really mean to fill the string with the character zero (value 48 or 0x30 [assuming ASCII before some pedant downvotes my answer and points out that there are other encodings]), or with a NUL (character of the value zero). The latter is `0`, not `'0'`

```
   scanf("%s",M);
   scanf("%s",W);
   i = 0;m = 0;w = 0;
   while (M[i] != '0')
          {
              ++m; ++i;  // incrementing till array reaches '0'
          }
```

If you are looking for the end of the string, you should be using `0`, not `'0'` (as per above).

Of course, `scanf` will put a `0` a the end of the string for you, so there's no need to fill the whole string with `0` [or `'0'`].

And `strlen` is an existing function that will give the length of a C style string, and will most likely have a more clever algorithm than just checking each character and increment two variables, making it faster [for long strings at least].

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `memset` when using `scanf`, scanf adds the terminating `'\0'` to string.

Also, `strlen` is more simple way to determine string's length:

```
scanf("%s %s", M, W); // provided that M and W contain enough space to store the string
m = strlen(M); // don't forget #include <string.h>
w = strlen(W);
```

Answer (score 0):

C-style strlen without memset may looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned strlen(const char *str) {
    const char *p = str;
    unsigned len = 0;
    while (*p != '\0') {
        len++;
        *p++;
    }
    return len;
}

int main() {
    cout << strlen("C-style string");
    return 0;
}
```

It's return 14.